# FFmpeg bitstream filter that can take two inputs

Tags: filter, ffmpeg, bitstream

I tried looking into the FFmpeg documentation, but couldn't find any bitstream filter that could take two inputs.

Is this not possible by design, or has such a use-case just not come up until now?

Comment: Can you give an example of a BSF that would require multiple inputs?

Comment: A filter that can for example compare some metadata present in two bit streams, or that can decode 2 bit streams and compute PSNR.

Comment: PSNR requires a comparison of the decoded streams, and it already [exists](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#psnr).

Comment: Yes. I used PSNR just as an example. I basically want to compute some quality metrics on the decoded output (by comparing with source stream). I want to do this computation as a part of decoding process as it will be computationally efficient.

Comment: @Gyan 608 embedding without transcode